# VS2010 Code Analysis and CA1800 : Microsoft Performance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have the code below which I know isn't optimal. I ran the Code Analysis and it gave me the warning

```
CA1800 : Microsoft.Performance : 'customField', a variable, is cast to type 'DateCustomFieldRef' multiple times in method 'Customer.CustomerToUpdat(SearchResult)'. Cache the result of the 'as' operator or direct cast in order to eliminate the redundant castclass instruction.
```

and I really don't understand what to do.

```
CustomFieldRef[] customFields = customer.customFieldList;
for (int f = 3; f < customFields.Length; f++)
{
    CustomFieldRef customField = customFields[f];
    if (customField is DateCustomFieldRef)
        {
            DateCustomFieldRef dateField = (DateCustomFieldRef)customField;
                if (dateField.internalId != null && dateField.internalId == "created_date")
                    {
                            createdDate = dateField.value.ToString();
                        }
                }
                if (customField is StringCustomFieldRef)
                {
                    StringCustomFieldRef tradingNameField = (StringCustomFieldRef)customField;
                        if (businessNameField.internalId != null && businessNameField.internalId == "business_name")
                        {
                            businessName = businessNameField.value;
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Could someone please give me a code example or explain further what it really means?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in code like:

```
if (customField is DateCustomFieldRef)
{
  DateCustomFieldRef dateField = (DateCustomFieldRef)customField;
```

These are multiple casts.

Better:

```
DateCustomFieldRef fieldasDate = customField as DateCustomFieldFRef

if (fieldasDate != null)
{
  blablabla using fieldasdate
```

This avoids the multiple casts.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you're casting (which can be costly) the `customField` variable multiple times, and that you'd be better of by casting only once.

You can use the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator to achieve that, since the `as` operator performs the cast and returns an instance of the desired type, or NULL if the object could not be casted to the desired type.

Like this:

```
DateCustomFieldRef customField = customFields[f] as DateCustomFieldRef; // the as operator returns null if the casting did not succeed (that is, customFields[f] is not a DatecustomFieldRef instance

if (customField != null)
{
     DateCustomFieldRef dateField = customField;
     if (dateField.internalId != null && dateField.internalId == "created_date")
     {
           createdDate = dateField.value.ToString();
     }
}
else
{
    var stringField = customFields[f] as StringCustomFieldRef;
    if (stringField != null )
    {
        StringCustomFieldRef tradingNameField = stringField;
        if (businessNameField.internalId != null && businessNameField.internalId == "business_name")
        {
            businessName = businessNameField.value;
        }
    }
}
```

But, I believe that there probably exists an even better solution (although I do not know your project, nor your code), but wouldn't it be possible to abstract some things away ?

Perhaps you have a `CustomField` baseclass, and `DateCustomFieldRef` and `StringCustomFieldRef` inherit from that `Customfield` base-class.
If that's the case, you could create a virtual (or maybe even abstract) method in the `CustomField` base-class, which is overriden in each child-class, which actually returns the value of that field.

Like this:

```
public class CustomField<T>
{

    public string Internalid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public T Value
    { 
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string GetStringRepresentation()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}

public class DateCustomField : CustomField<DateTime>
{
    public override string GetStringRepresentation()
    {
         return Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

Your code can then look much more simple:

```
foreach( CustomField f in customFields )
{
     if( f.InternalId == "created_date" )
     {
         createdDate = f.GetStringRepresentation();
     }
     if( f.InternalId == "business_name" )
     {
         businessName = f.GetStringRepresentation();
     }
}
```

(The code above could be made more simple and clean, but you'll get the drift.)